# How can ı do read excel with sheetjs in Clojurescript?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I have a excel file. I imported sheetjs (https://sheetjs.com/). I want to read to sheet data. How can ı do read excel with sheetjs in Clojurescript?

The project written with https://github.com/day8/re-frame

Comment: This is too broad Akaza. The library seems [well documented](https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/) and js interop for Clojurescript is also pretty well documented, what *specifically* are you having trouble with? I'm not going to say that questions with no user-written code in them are *always* off-topic, but pretty nearly (including this one).

Comment: ı am new about clojure. I ask to how can use xlsx with clojure. Thank you so much. my answer in comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should put you in the right direction - it opens a file called datadump.xlsx in the same folder as index.html (the root folder of your app). Easy to adapt to upload a file through a form. In the main namespace you'd just call `(data/read-local-file)`.

```
(ns data
  (:require [reagent.core :as r]
            [reagent.dom :as rd]
            [re-frame.core :as rf]
            ["xlsx" :as XLSX]))

(defn read-sheet [wb sheet-name]
  (let [sheet (aget (. wb -Sheets) sheet-name)
        data (XLSX/utils.sheet_to_json sheet #js {:header 1})
        dataclj (js->clj data)
        kk (map keyword (first dataclj))
        outdata (into [] (for [line (rest dataclj)] (zipmap kk line)))]

    (rf/dispatch [:source-data outdata])))

(defn read-local-file []
  (let [xhr (js/XMLHttpRequest.)]
    (.open xhr "GET" "datadump.xlsx" true)
    (set! (.-responseType xhr) "blob")
    (set! (.-onload xhr)
          (fn []
            (let [reader (js/FileReader.)]
              (.readAsArrayBuffer reader (.-response xhr))
              (set! (.-onload reader)
                    (fn [evt]
                      (let [ab (-> evt .-target .-result)
                            wb (XLSX/read ab #js {:type "array" :cellDates true})
                            sn (. wb -SheetNames)]
                        (read-sheet wb (first sn))))))))
    (.send xhr)))
```